# Pulling countries from a database, using leaflet to give them coordinates

Tags: leaflet

I am currently working on a program that pulls countries and coordinates from a database. I am pinning them on a map after gathering them. I am having no trouble when receiving both the coordinates and the country but when the coordinates aren't available I can't pin on the map just based on the country. I was hoping there was a leaflet method that would allow me to geolocate solely based on a country that would pin in the middle of the country.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no core Leaflet method for doing this. However, there are some (3rd-party) Leaflet geocoding plugins that might do the trick. Take at look here: http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#geocoding. Specifically, there is a geonames plugin that looks especially promising: https://github.com/consbio/Leaflet.Geonames.

Leaflet or not, this should be fairly easy to accomplish using a simple RESTful API call. Here's a Plunker where this is done: https://plnkr.co/edit/B2OF0D1nlBuNW6r2rqVL

Below is the operative section:

```js
$( document ).ready(
  function() {
    // Get the latlng from rest countries
    getCountryLocation = function() {
      $('#country').html( $('#country_input').val() );
      $.ajax(
        {
          url: "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/" + $('#country_input').val() + "?fullText=true", 
          success: function( result ) {
            var latlng = result[0].latlng;
            
            $("#latlng").html( latlng[0] + ", " + latlng[1] );
          }
        }
      );
    }
    
    // Do the inital setup
    getCountryLocation();
    
    $('#go').click(
      getCountryLocation
    );
  }
);
```